# How can I recover files from a FAT disk image in their original locations?

Tags: data-recovery, data-loss, disk-image

I had an MP3 player that deleted most of its files. I created an 8GB image file with dd right away.

I looked at and tried to use some of the recovery software, but they just give me a bunch of files, usually unnamed and not in the right place in the tree. Some of them didn't work with image files. What programs can I use to recover the deleted files so I can copy them directly to the drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try with [TestDist](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk:_undelete_file_for_FAT)?
Following the help it said

> To recover a partition from a media image or repair a filesystem image, run
>
> - `testdisk image.dd` to carve a raw disk image
> - `testdisk image.E01` to recover files from an Encase EWF image
> - `testdisk 'image.*'` if the Encase image is split into several files.

So you can try to follow that path.

You may find interesting:

- [TestDisk: undelete file for FAT](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk:_undelete_file_for_FAT)

Comment: Thanks, I had tried teskdisk but it didn't show the mounted image file, hadn't realized it could be fed it as an argument.

Comment: You're welcome. To be honest the first time I read the instruction page for a couple of long seconds I believed that was only  a feature of the OS/2 version... :-)